# Meteor JQuery Start Rating Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am getting issues trying to use the follow Meteor Package: dandv:jquery-rateit.

I am using it for a ticket system where each update will have a start rating. But when I have more than 1 comment the second one always return 0 value.

Here is my code:

JS:

```js
Template.rating.events({
    'click .rateit': function(e){
    var rating = $('#rate').rateit('value');
    console.log(rating);
    Session.set('UpdateId', this._id);
    var UpdateId = this._id;
    console.log(UpdateId);
    /*Meteor.call('saveRate',rating,UpdateId);*/

    return false;
  }
});


Template.rating.rendered = function () {
  this.$('.rateit').rateit();
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="Update">

    {{#each Updates}}
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">Update</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" nowrap align="left">Created By:</td>
                        <td width="35%" align="left">{{createdBy.username}}</td>
                        <td width="15%" nowrap align="left">Created At:</td>
                        <td width="35%" align="left">{{formatDate createdAt}}</td>
                        <td width="15%" nowrap align="left">Rating:</td>

                        <td width="35%" align="left">{{> rating}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="4">{{description}}</td>
                    </tr>  
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="rating">
  <div class="rateit" id="rate"></div>
</template>
```

Now when I try to rate the second comment is return 0. Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/ejaTI98X

No matter what star do I select, it always return 0. I think that the error should be probably in the HTML.

I really appreciate all your help on it. If you have any question just let me know.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over Updates and I assume there are more than one update. For each update you call the template {{>rateit}} which then renders a div with id=rate, so you will end up with several divs with the same id, so you don't really know which one $('#rate') you are accessing.

In your event handler you also use the global jQuery handler.

I suggest you use the following pattern instead to scope jQuery local to the templates context

```
Template.rating.events({
    'click .rateit': function(e,template){
     var rating = template.$('.rateit').rateit('value');
     console.log(rating);
     Session.set('UpdateId', template.data._id);
     var UpdateId = template.data._id;
     console.log(UpdateId);
     /*Meteor.call('saveRate',rating,UpdateId);*/

     return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The issue has been fixed

Comment: Mark the answer as useful (up arrow) in case other people have the same problem